# ie9 Error: 'Blob' is undefined

Tags: javascript, csv, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-9, blob

this http://jsfiddle.net/bCRm3/17/

(Kendo grid export to csv)

works fine in firefox, chrome and IE11

in ie9 im getting

```
            blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' }); //Blob.js
            saveAs(blob, fileName); //FileSaver.js
```

'Blob' is undefined 
show, line 141 character 17

is there a way around this for ie9? (im not sure if this works on ie10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check `Blob` object browser compatibility:

**Browser compatibility**

> ```
> Chrome  Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari (WebKit)
> 20      13.0 (13.0)     10                  12.10   6 (536.10)
> ```

Please note that this is not supported by all browsers including IE9 or ealier:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: thanks, is there a cross browser JavaScript solution?