# Saving html page into .doc works on firefox, doesn't work on ie - how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, orbeon, xforms

It's my first time posting here so please bear with me as I'll try to be as exhaustive as possible. I'm currently trying to create a button in my code that, when pressed, saves a div of an HTML page (containing a mix of text and tables) to a .doc document. I successfully achieved this result on firefox, but on ie, the button does absolutely nothing.

On ie9 I receive on the console a "SCRIPT5009: 'Blob' non è definito 
orbeon-7af471470dd4066fbc9a72c21920d3b8e08edd89.js, Riga 60 Carattere 7" error - Blob is undefined - line 60 char 7.

While I know that it is not supported by MS anymore I'm kinda stuck on the browsers to use since I know that some users of the site (actually most of them) will use ie9. Also, I'm stuck with a very old Orbeon form that I can't update (sigh).

The code I wrote works fine on Firefox 66.0.2 (64 bit) - but gives the above error on ie 9.0.8112.16421. Since I received the above error I tried to add a Blob.js script since I thought it was an issue in interpreting that but I only obtained a completely "empty" page without even the button. Before I reached this half working solution I also tried - filesaver.js html-docx.js and googoose.js. None of these worked for me.

The solution I ended up with is a js file

export2doc.js

```
$("#export").click(function(){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></meta></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById("tabs-2").innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
        });

    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    filename='';
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';

    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        var blobURL   = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
});
```

```html
<xh:head>
...
    <xh:script src="/config/myjs/Export2Doc.js"></xh:script>
...
</xh:head>

<xh:body class="maincontent">
...
<xh:div id="tabsT">
    <xh:div id="tabs-1">
    ...
    </xh:div>
    <xh:div id="tabs-2">
        <xh:table>
            <xh:tr>
                <xh:td>
                 text that can also be a query result returning a text string
                </xh:td>
            </xh:tr>
        </xh:table>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <xh:table>
        ....
        </xh:table>
    </xh:div>

    <xforms:trigger appearance="full" id="export">
    <xforms:label>Esporta in doc</xforms:label>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xh:div>
```

I dunno what or how can I try to make it work on ie9. I expected to save on both FF and IE since, from what I read, the msSaveOrOpenBlob should have taken care of the ie part... but it doesn't seem it works and I'm totally lost on how to fix it. I don't mind changing my code or approach even completely if it allows me to get the job done: a button that when pressed saves the above HTML div into a .doc on both ie and FF. Right now it seems that only the firefox part is working as intended. Is there a way to bypass the blob compatibility issue since even including the blob.js doesn't seem to work? Is there another way that can allow me to save to doc in ie9?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ie9 Error: 'Blob' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830134/ie9-error-blob-is-undefined)

Comment: Already seen that before posting and already imported the blob.js that was pointed there, but the solution didn't work for me (as stated above). I need some kind of different way to save html -> doc in ie9 or (that would be the best outcome for me) to fix the above code somehow so it works on ie9 too...

Comment: You added that after I commented lol. Chances are you are going to need to find a blob polyfill and import it before this script. If you tried Blob.js and it didnt work, include why it didnt work.

Comment: expanding what I wrote above; I tried to import blob.js - firefox still ok - ie though doesn't show anything anymore. Only the layout of the page stays but all the datas/text in it is empty. Even the save button is not present. On the console the received error is SCRIPT1002: Errore di sintassi 
orbeon-7af471470dd4066fbc9a72c21920d3b8e08edd89.js, Riga 183 Carattere 9
SCRIPT445: Azione non valida per l'oggetto 
orbeon-989e5dc65fbc1e4e6e17606734ac9b25779353fa.js, Riga 139 Carattere 817 I believe, and I may be wrong, the old orbeon I'm using has some issues with what's in the blob.js

Comment: IE10 should have blob, do you really need to support 9?

Comment: Unluckily for me I do.. this will be accessed mostly by firefox (which works fine) and the old ie9 version above that won't be updated anytime soon due to assorted policies... sigh - p.s. if I can't find a way to make ti work I'll just put up a disclaimer on what can or can not use the button... but.. that's somthing I'd like to avoid if possible

Comment: Hi Marco, if I read the Italian error message correctly, it sounds like IE9 complains about a syntax error in `orbeon-989e5dc65fbc1e4e6e17606734ac9b25779353fa.js`. But if you don't include that `blob.js`, that JavaScript file works, doesn't it? Is the `blob.js` included in that file? If so, I am wondering if this couldn't be caused by the JavaScript being combined: look at the file at the line in question, and see if anything looks wrong. When files are concatenated, `;` need to be added that otherwise wouldn't be needed; maybe one has to be added at the end of `blob.js`.

Comment: Hi Marco, did you get a chance to check what the syntax error is, per my previous comment, or have you maybe solved that issue in some other way? ‑Alex

Comment: Sorry I'm this late in answering.. no it's not caused by that. I tried to both <chain> the files and to simpy load it above in the main page (as some other scripts) but without any kind of working result. I went in and modified slighlty the blob.js to try and fit the commands that were not accepted... but it simply rebounds against the old orbeon not accepting them. Since I couldn't find a different solution at the moment I just went with the aforementioned disclaimer.... >.<